# Using Pandoc to generate a PDF from multiple files - in order

Tags: bash, pdf, latex, pandoc

I'm using the following command to convert 5 files (1 Markdown, 4 HTML) to PDF using Pandoc:

```
pandoc --toc --latex-engine=xelatex ${SOURCE_DIR}/* -o ${DST_DIR}/${DST}.pdf
```

It successfully does so, but in whatever order it wants. Is there any way to specify what order these files should be added to the singular PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to do it alphabetically by file name, so that's a workaround.

Comment: yes, the `*` is actually a shell operator. So exact implementation depends on which shell you use... e.g. bash.

Comment: Yep, I tagged bash to the post for that reason, but should've mentioned it in the post as well. :) Sorry.